# Storing only selected fields and not storing _all in pyes/elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, pyes

I am trying to use pyes with elasticsearch as full text search engine, I store only UUIDs and indexes of string fields, actual data is stored in MonogDB and retrieved using UUIDs. Unfortunately, I am unable to create a mapping that wouldn't store original data, I've tried various combinations of "store"/"source" fields and disabling "_all" but I can still get text of indexed fields. It seems that documentation is misleading on this topic as it's just a copy of original docs.

Can anyone please provide an example of mapping that would only store some fields and not the original document JSON?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure, you could use something like this (with two fields, 'uuid' and 'body'):

```
{
  "mytype" : {
    "_source" : {
      "enabled" : false
    },
    "_all" : {
      "enabled" : false
    },
    "properties" : {
      "data" : {
        "store" : "no",
        "type" : "string"
      },
      "uuid" : {
        "store" : "yes",
        "type" : "string",
        "index" : "not_analyzed"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, after checking your example, documentation and docs I was able to spot my error: 1. I was missing _content field, 2. I've missed the properties key and was having special field on the same level as my custom ones.