# ElasticSearch vs. MongoDB for Caching User Data

Tags: mongodb, elasticsearch

Up to this point, I have been using MongoDB (Node.js + Mongoose) to save posts which belong to a user, so that I can later retrieve them to display in a stream (just like Facebook, Twitter, etc.)

It recently became necessary to allow the user to deeply search his stream; MongoDB's search was insufficient, so I implemented ElasticSearch on my servers (Amazon EC2 m1.large instances running CentOS, FWIW).

**My question**: I'm now in a position that I'm duplicating the data between MongoDB (where the user's stream is cached) and ElasticSearch (where it is searched).

Is there any disadvantage to moving my cache ENTIRELY into ElasticSearch, getting rid of the MongoDB all together? It seems a waste to double the storage, and there's no other place that I'm accessing this data (it is only used when presenting/searching the stream of posts).

Specifically, I want to make sure I'm not overlooking anything re: performance. I like the idea of reducing MongoDB as a bottleneck, yet I worry about the memory overhead of ElasticSearch. MongoDB runs on its own server in my cloud setup, whereas ElasticSearch is running on the same instances as node.js. This means I would have **MORE** ElasticSearch servers (the node.js servers are in an auto-scaling array), but they each are not **DEDICATED** servers (unlike MongoDB).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The only big obstacle to using ES as a "primary datasource" is that there isn't a good backup mechanism right now.  The ES team is working on it and expect it to be out by the end of the year, but in the mean time, you'll have to implement your own backup scripts.

As far as performance, it's really hard to say because almost every situation is unique.  ES benefits from memory - so more is always better.  In particular, sorts/filters/facets/geo all like to eat memory.  If you aren't doing much in the way of faceting, for example, you may be fine with less memory.

ES doesn't need to run on a dedicated node...but it will happily use as many resources as you give it.

Comment: Interesting. I thought when I used the "Elasticsearch on EC2" tutorial that the data was all stored into a S3 bucket? While this may not be a "backup" per se, it at least provides persistency (ie, if a given server goes down, the data is not lost, correct?) http://www.elasticsearch.org/tutorials/2011/08/22/elasticsearch-on-ec2.html

Comment: You're correct, although it should be noted that the S3 gateway has been depreciated (https://github.com/elasticsearch/elasticsearch/issues/2458).  In general though, that's basically what I meant...you need something (S3 gateway, cron scripts to snapshot, etc) to provide a restore mechanism, whereas other datastores provide this implicitly. Not a huge deal, and ES is actively working on providing this functionality themselves.

Answer (score 2):

Another option is to use just the elastic search indexes. You can choose to not save data in a readable format, so you search in ES and then retrieve documents from MongoDB to your user as needed.

The question bellow comments exactly on that.
[Storing only selected fields and not storing _all in pyes/elasticsearch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12479583/storing-only-selected-fields-and-not-storing-all-in-pyes-elasticsearch)